# OrderBy IndexOf another list

Tags: c#

I feel like this is simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

If I have this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TestClass test1 = new TestClass(){ID = 1, text = "STRING ONE"};
        TestClass test2 = new TestClass(){ID = 2, text = "STRING TWO"};
        TestClass test3 = new TestClass(){ID = 3, text = "STRING THREE"};
        TestClass test4 = new TestClass(){ID = 4, text = "STRING FOUR"};

        List<TestClass> lstTestClasses = new List<TestClass>();
        lstTestClasses.Add(test1);
        lstTestClasses.Add(test2);
        lstTestClasses.Add(test3);
        lstTestClasses.Add(test4);

        List<string> lstCategories = new List<string>() { "STRING TWO", "STRING ONE", "STRING THREE"};

        var orderStrings = lstTestClasses.OrderBy(x => lstCategories.IndexOf(x.text)).ToList();

        foreach(var item in orderStrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.text);
        }

        // Output:
            STRING FOUR
            STRING TWO
            STRING ONE
            STRING THREE
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get `STRING FOUR` to come last and not first, since it is not included in `lstCategories`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
int i = 0;
var orderStrings = lstTestClasses.OrderBy(x => 
                                 (i = lstCategories.IndexOf(x.text)) < 0 ? int.MaxValue : i)
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: so what does the `-1` turn into with `int.MaxValue`?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid `-1` is less than `0`, so if `IndexOf` returns `-1`, then `OrderBy` will receive `int.MaxValue` instead.

Comment: I get that part, I was just asking what is the value of `int.MaxValue`?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid [It's the maximum value of an `int`, meaning `2,147,483,647`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I guess `2,147,483,647`?

Answer (score 0):

Since the value is not found, `IndexOf` returns `-1` which places it all the way at the beginning of the collection.

I suggest to check if `IndexOf` is less than `0`, if then, set it to `Int32.MaxValue` in order to place it at the end of the collection.

As in:

```
TestClass test1 = new TestClass() { ID = 1, text = "STRING ONE" };
TestClass test2 = new TestClass() { ID = 2, text = "STRING TWO" };
TestClass test3 = new TestClass() { ID = 3, text = "STRING THREE" };
TestClass test4 = new TestClass() { ID = 4, text = "STRING FOUR" };

List<TestClass> lstTestClasses = new List<TestClass>();
lstTestClasses.Add(test1);
lstTestClasses.Add(test2);
lstTestClasses.Add(test3);
lstTestClasses.Add(test4);

List<string> lstCategories = new List<string>() { "STRING TWO", "STRING ONE", "STRING THREE" };

var orderStrings = lstTestClasses.OrderBy(x => {
    var index = lstCategories.IndexOf(x.text);
    return index < 0 ? Int32.MaxValue : index;
}).ToList();

foreach (var item in orderStrings)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.text);
}
```